# I need a simple code to remove decimal in my javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. this showing a result with 8-9 decimal after main number. I want only 2 decimal to show after main number.

```
var data = resp.data
Object.keys(data).map(q => {
  Object.keys(data[q]).map(r => {
    console.log($('.rate_' + r + '_' + q), data[q][r])
    $('.rate_' + r + '_' + q).text(data[q][r] + '%')
  })
})
```

Comment: can you share the input object with values, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to do that with the parameter being the number of digits after the decimal point. That assumes you have a `Number` already. If you have a string you need to parse it first using [`Number.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```js
const test = 23213423.23423423;
console.log(test.toFixed(2));

const testStr = "23213423.23423423";
const parsed = Number.parseFloat(testStr);
if (!isNaN(parsed)) console.log(parsed.toFixed(2));
else console.log("The string is not a number!");
```

Answer (score 0):

**working example**

```js
const data = {
  a: { aa: 10.1234}, 
  b: {bb: 1.12345}
};

const out = [];
Object.keys(data).map( q => {
  Object.keys(data[q]).map( r => {        
    out.push(data[q][r].toFixed(2))
  })
})

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
const numbers = [
   1.1234567,
   10.14,
   0,
   44.178,
   15.1,
   23445.212124,
   2373872387283
];

numbers.forEach(x => {
   const result = Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
   console.info(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Syntax

```js
Math.round(x)
```

##### Parameters

`x`  -> A number

##### Return value

The value of the given number is rounded to the nearest integer.

```js
const data = {
  a: {aa: 10.4234}, 
  b: {bb: 1.52345},
  c: {cc:708.957}
};

Object.keys(data).map(q => {
  Object.keys(data[q]).map(r => {
    console.log(`Rate of ${q}: {${r}: ${Math.round(data[q][r])}}`)
  })
})
```